# Linking Add to cart button on my website to the cart

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to link my add to cart button on each of my web pages to the cart but I dont know how to do this.  I am having to do this for an assignment and need to hand this in Friday.

Could someone please help?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>HTML5 Local Storage Project</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink- 
to-fit=no">
<meta name="rating" content="General">
<meta name="expires" content="never">
<meta name="language" content="English, EN">
<meta name="description" content="Shopping cart project with HTML5 and 
JavaScript">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML5,CSS,JavaScript, html5 session storage, 
html5 local storage">
<script src="Storage.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="StorageStyle.css">
</head>
<form name="ShoppingList">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Shopping cart</legend>
    <label>Item: <input type="text" name="name"></label>
    <label>Quantity: <input type="text" name="data"></label>

    <input type="button" value="Save"   onclick="SaveItem()">
    <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="ModifyItem()">
    <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="RemoveItem()">
</fieldset>
<div id="items_table">
    <h2>Shopping List</h2>
    <table id="list"></table>
    <label><input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="ClearAll()">
    * Delete all items</label>
</div>
</form>



<div class= "paris">
 <img src ="../IMAGES/paris.jpg" alt = "sale offer" width ="315" height 
 ="200">
<h3>Flights to Charles de gaulle Now Only £95</h3>
  <button>Add to Cart</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Im not asking for someone to write the code for me just asking some advice ion how to do that

Comment: Are you using any server side language? It would be best to add the button by including its HTML snippet on the server

Comment: its a client side web development course and we are using codio

Comment: would you know of a website that would help me on this

Comment: I have the following code in the cart html

Comment: Very hard to tell. Can you please [edit] the question and include more details? I need to know the HTML structure of the button and the page itself - It will also help others to help you :)

Comment: the following code html is from the actual page im trying to link to the cart

Comment: sorry for the multiple posts but it would only allow me to add so many characters

Comment: No, please [edit] and include it in the question itself so it will be more readable `:)`

Comment: You can also take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) about including HTML snippet in HTML

Comment: Hi Alon  I have added the cart code to my question and also a part of my webpage that shows the add to cart button that I trying to link

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/05mpg76n/) maybe? You can save the code in a js file and add it to any page. I also added the functions that are attached to the buttons [here](https://jsfiddle.net/05mpg76n/1/) so you can implement the relevant logic of the shopping cart

Comment: Hi Alon so the bits you added, do I add this to the JS File I have, so what would need to go in my actual page where the add to cart button is to link it

Comment: You save the code in a .js file (For example: `shopping_cart.js`), then you just includ that file **at the bottom** of each page `<script src="shopping_cart.js"></script>` (Before the closing `</body>` tag)

Comment: I have added this to the bottom of my html page and when I press the add to cart button nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what you're asking since there's no specific question, but maybe you're looking for something like this?

```js
const saveButton = document.querySelector('input[value="Save"]');

saveButton.addEventListener('click', saveItem);

function saveItem() {
  const item = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]');
  const qty = document.querySelector('input[name="data"]');
  const list = document.querySelector('#list');
  
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.textContent = `${item.value} ${qty.value}`;
  
  list.insertAdjacentElement('beforeEnd', tr);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>HTML5 Local Storage Project</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink- 
to-fit=no">
<meta name="rating" content="General">
<meta name="expires" content="never">
<meta name="language" content="English, EN">
<meta name="description" content="Shopping cart project with HTML5 and 
JavaScript">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML5,CSS,JavaScript, html5 session storage, 
html5 local storage">
<meta name="author" content="dcwebmakers.com">
<script src="Storage.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="StorageStyle.css">
</head>
<form name="ShoppingList">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Shopping cart</legend>
    <label>Item: <input type="text" name="name"></label>
    <label>Quantity: <input type="text" name="data"></label>

    <input type="button" value="Save" >
    <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="ModifyItem()">
    <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="RemoveItem()">
</fieldset>
<div id="items_table">
    <h2>Shopping List</h2>
    <table id="list"></table>
    <label><input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="ClearAll()">
    * Delete all items</label>
</div>
</form>
```

Note it's best practice to use eventListeners and not have function calls in your HTML.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Michael I have added your code but nothing happens.  Basically I have a website that I am doing for an assignment which is for a package holiday and I have hyperlinks to different pages on each page such as flights I have a picture of Dusseldorf and underneath I have an add to cart button, its this I need code for that actually adds this to the cart but I am at a halt with this.

Comment: @gazgaz5 what do you mean by "adds this to the cart"? What is the cart? there's a thousand ways cart functionality can be coded. You're really not giving us enough information to answer your question.

Comment: How can I give you the code to one of my pages?  Then maybe what I said will make sense

Comment: @gazgaz5 you can edit your question above or create a jsfiddle or similar and link that here

Comment: Where it has add to cart I would like it when pressed to add this particular thing to a cart but i dont know how to do this

Comment: @gazgaz5 I still don't know what the cart is. Is it an element in the DOM? Is it an object in web storage? Is it on the server? Maybe research "how to store cart data" get you closer to a specific question.

Comment: it is like any website when you buy something you add it to a basket and then go to a checkout instead I have called mine a cart

Comment: I could change it to add to basket

Comment: @gazgaz5 what I'm saying is there's a thousand ways to code that basket/cart. You have not provided enough details regarding how you want to code yours. Please do some research and post a specific question if you have one.